# Use an emoji in a MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, emoji

Is it possible to use an emoji in a mysql trigger?

Currently when I save the trigger with the emoji in it, the emoji changes to a ?

My table is set to DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin

```
/*!50003 SET SESSION SQL_MODE="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION" */;;
/*!50003 CREATE */ /*!50017 DEFINER=`dbadmin`@`%` */ /*!50003 TRIGGER `push`     AFTER UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (NEW.deviceToken != OLD.deviceToken) THEN
INSERT INTO pushqueue (deviceToken, message)
SELECT NEW.deviceToken, "Thank you for downloading. ? ";
END IF;
END */;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimalistic code that does not work for you?

Comment: added code to original post

Comment: Have you tried to insert the character as unicode? Also, even the storage is correct, you can lose information on the output channel. Check your connection settings, your app encondings, etc.

Comment: Agree with @GaborSch. This may be something to do with the client, and not the DB encoding.

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL command line I can't reproduce the error:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.18    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET NAMES utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pushqueue`, `users`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    ->   `deviceToken` BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pushqueue` (
    ->   `deviceToken` BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `message` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `push` AFTER UPDATE ON `users`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   IF (NEW.`deviceToken` != OLD.`deviceToken`) THEN
    ->     INSERT INTO `pushqueue` (`deviceToken`, `message`)
    ->     SELECT NEW.`deviceToken`, 'Thank you for downloading. ';
    ->   END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS//
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                       |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1300 | Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'Thank ...' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> INSERT INTO `users` (`deviceToken`)
    -> VALUES (UUID_SHORT());
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `deviceToken` INTO @`deviceToken`
    -> FROM `users`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`deviceToken`;
+-------------------+
| @`deviceToken`    |
+-------------------+
| 25124118424715283 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE `users` SET `deviceToken` = UUID_SHORT()
    -> WHERE `deviceToken` = @`deviceToken`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `deviceToken`
    -> FROM `users`;
+-------------------+
| deviceToken       |
+-------------------+
| 25124118424715284 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `deviceToken`, `message`
    -> FROM `pushqueue`;
+-------------------+---------------------------------+
| deviceToken       | message                         |
+-------------------+---------------------------------+
| 25124118424715284 | Thank you for downloading.      |
+-------------------+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r8sjAhD3T16So5sSnePbCH/0).